# Disable pagination in DSE 4.7 when running Solr CQL queries

Tags: solr, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I am unable to find the driver option to turn off paging as indicated in the documentation -

"Note: When using CQL Solr queries with Cassandra pagination enabled, you might experience a performance slowdown because Solr is not able to use its query result cache when pagination is configured. If you do not want to paginate through large result sets, disable pagination when running CQL Solr queries. See the driverdocumentation."

I see that the 2.1.6 driver has a new call called Statement.setPagingState() but that seems to be for a different purpose. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the fetchSize to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Check out the [Java driver docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryOptions.html) for details.